# What happens to the existing customers with active in-app auto renewable subscription when the app and the in-app purchase is removed from sale

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I would like to remove an app from app store which currently has auto renewable in-app purchase. What happens to the users who have active auto renewable in-app purchase when I remove both the app and the auto renewable in-app purchase from sale?
Will the existing users still get their subscription renewed? If yes how long can they renew?
If the user uninstalls the app from device and then restore app from iTunes(as it is not available in the app store for sale) will the subscription still be active and renewed?

Update: What happens to the auto renewable subscription if the app is removed from sale and in-app subscription is still in sale. Will the user still get the subscription auto renewed?

Comment: The subscription will remain active until the end of their current subscription period.  If you have removed the in-app purchase from sale then they will not be able to renew (the automatic renewal will not take place).  If they re-install the app then they will still have access to the subscription until it expires (They can restore purchases to get access to their current subscription).

Comment: Thanks Paul. What happens if only the app is removed from sale and the in-app purchase is till available. Will the subscription auto renew for existing customers?

Comment: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7013b314c this document has "Removing an app from the App Store doesn’t automatically remove its associated in-app purchases. Customers can still download in-app purchases unless you explicitly remove them from sale." But i am not clear whether the existing subscriptions will be auto renewed.